# I failed to install MinGW on Windows 10

Tags: mingw

I failed to install MinGW on Windows 10. When I ran MinGW
*get-setup.exe*, modified the installation path, and clicked the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button, the following error appeared.

My system is 64-bit Windows 10, the firewall is closed, and I have also tried running as an administrator.

Error:

```
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.tar.xz?download:cannot open URLmingw-get: *** ERROR *** http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.tar.xz?download:cannot open URL
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-setup-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-dll.tar.xz?download: download failed
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-setup-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-xml.tar.xz?download:cannot open URL
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-setup-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-xml.tar.xz?download: download failed
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-gui.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-lic.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-setup-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-dll.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** INFO *** setup: unpacking mingw-get-setup-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-xml.tar.xz
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: required archive file is not available
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** unpack: aborted due to previous download failure
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** setup: unable to continue
```

Comment: I'd recommend using mingw-w64 instead, it is all around better than mingw.org

Comment: Project requirements must use mingw.org.

Comment: My condolences to you

Comment: Are there any firewalls or proxies at play? You could also try downloading the archives manually.

Comment: It is estimated that it is a problem of permissions. Some companies use VPN tools. They can download them, but several of my friends and I can't download them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get MinGW-64 from http://mingw-w64.org/, or if you prefer to have the latest version that doesn't require an installer you can get the personal build from http://winlibs.com/.

Comment: Project requirements must use mingw.org.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the setup in the local folder and run it as administrator in the local folder

Answer (score -1):

juts run the installer as an administrator, and you'll be good to go.